# Python Script is plotting but I stillketting an error

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I am submitting a script in Python but endedup getting this error:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

~/grader/assignment1_student_solution.py in ()

```
300 

301
```

--> 302 accuracy_plot()

```
303 

304
```

~/grader/assignment1_student_solution.py in accuracy_plot()

```
248 

249 def accuracy_plot():
```

--> 250     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
251 

252     get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'notebook')
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in ()

```
113 

114 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
```

--> 115 _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()

```
116 

117 _IP_REGISTERED = None
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py in pylab_setup()

```
 30     # imports. 0 means only perform absolute imports.

 31     backend_mod = __import__(backend_name,
```

---> 32                              globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)

```
 33 

 34     # Things we pull in from all backends
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py in ()

```
 14 

 15 from .backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
```

---> 16 from .backend_qt5 import QtCore

```
 17 from .backend_qt5 import QtGui

 18 from .backend_qt5 import FigureManagerQT
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py in ()

```
 24 

 25 from matplotlib.widgets import SubplotTool
```

---> 26 import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions

```
 27 

 28 from .qt_compat import (QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName,
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py in ()

```
 18 import matplotlib

 19 from matplotlib import cm, markers, colors as mcolors
```

---> 20 import matplotlib.backends.qt_editor.formlayout as formlayout

```
 21 from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui

 22
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/formlayout.py in ()

```
 54 

 55 from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
```

---> 56 from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

```
 57 

 58
```

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py in ()

```
126     if QT_API == QT_API_PYQT5:

127         try:
```

--> 128             from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

```
129             _getSaveFileName = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName

130         except ImportError:
```

ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: 1/ the presentation could  be enhanced with a single bloc of code 2/ provide a code snippet recreating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing `libGL.so`.

`libGL.so` can be found in many packages depending on your graphic card. See [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so)

Choose the package that is suited for your graphic card and install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```